# how to update a listview in thread?

Tags: android

i want to get some information from the remote server and display that data in listview, i have retrieved the data from the server, but i don't know how to display that in the list view,
here is my code, in this code i have displayed a listview with static data and tried to update this list view by the data obtaining from the server,

i don't know where to update the list view, please anyone help me to do this

```
package com.listview;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ThreadTest mThreadTest;
ArrayList<String > arlist;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mThreadTest=new ThreadTest();       
      Thread tt=new Thread(mThreadTest);
      tt.start();   
//create a static arraylist to display it in listview
      arlist = new ArrayList<String>();
      arlist.add("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
      arlist.add("yyyyyyyyyyyy");
      ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, arlist);
      setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);       
//create listview

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
// When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });
    }

static public class ThreadTest implements Runnable
{
    ListViewActivity li=new ListViewActivity();             
    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;
    public  ArrayList al,arraylist;
    public void run() 
    {
//get some details from remote server as json string 

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        try
        {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxxxxx/clients/yyyyyy/city.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
         }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        try{                
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                    sb.append(line  );
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

/**************************************
             * result is [{"city_id":"1","city_name":"madurai"},{"city_id":"2","city_name":"coimbatore"},{"city_id":"3","city_name":"chennai"}]
             */

//parse the json string values

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                int id = row.getInt("city_id");                 
                String name = row.getString("city_name");
//add the cityname to arraylist to display it in listview after the thread exeucted
                arraylist.add(name);                                                    
            }            

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have found a good tutorial at http://www.sitepoint.com/loading-twitter-data-into-android-with-lists/ to do this,

Comment: Sorry Ramamoorthy please try to be more specific if you ask questions on stackoverflow. Just posting code and hoping for a solution won't work.

Comment: i want to create a listview in a Thread, is it possible to do this?

Comment: Just a friendly word of advice....please don't post hundreds of lines of code into a question. Reduce your sample code to just enough code to demonstrate your issue. That way you get better answers. Please have a read of this article: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 4):

To update UI, you should call a UI thread inside your thread like following

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
           ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, arlist);
  setListAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
} 
 });
```

Comment: Amazingly easy! Even better with lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2):

In a situation like this, I prefer to use AsyncTask as it breaks everything out for you and keeps things nice and organized. Example:

```
UpdateTask mTask = null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // All of your onCreate code goes here
    // ...
    setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    // ...

    mTask = new UpdateTask();
    mTask.execute();
}

public class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,JSONArray> {
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Add your HTTPClient code here
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        // Add code that loops through JSONArray and adds to adapter here
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = result.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = row.getInt("city_id");                 
            String name = row.getString("city_name");
            //add the cityname to arraylist to display it in listview after the thread exeucted
            arrayAdapter.add(name);                                                    
        }  
    }
}
```

I tried to keep the example short and to the point, but if you need more info on what to do just leave a comment and I'll try to clarify.

-Dan

Comment: i have tried setListAdapter inside onPostExecute i have met this error The Constructor  The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(CityActivity.UpdateTask, int, ArrayList) is undefined

Comment: setListAdapter should still be called in your onCreate where you had it. onPostExecute would loop through the JSONArray and add the results to the adapter. I will update the code above to reflect this.

Comment: i have updated the code, i could not create the list view here, have a look at this code and let me know the mistake i have made here.

Comment: In your case, you can reference the current Context from within the AsyncTask by using the current instance of the Activity. Example: ListViewActivity.this

Answer (score 1):

```
Oncreate(){
 Thread th=new Thread(this);
 th.start();
 }
```

Now do all work in thread except UI task and save all values to appropriate variable.

```
void run(){
//fetch data from webservice
handler.sendEmptymessage(0);
}
```

Now do UI task such as adding data to list in handler class

```
private Handler handler=new Handler(){
@Override
public void onHandleMessage(){
//Update list
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Handler` to send the arraylist to the main thread.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
   // create adapter and set to listview.  
  } 
};

static public class ThreadTest implements Runnable
{

        ......
        ......

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) 
        {
            JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = row.getInt("city_id");                 
            String name = row.getString("city_name");
            //add the cityname to arraylist to display it in listview after the thread exeucted
            arraylist.add(name);                                                    
        }            

        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = arraylist;
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

Comment: hi everybody thanks for your great help, it helps me lot and i have found good tutorial at http://www.sitepoint.com/loading-twitter-data-into-android-with-lists/